# Initialize clock for second Ethernet PHY before probing MDIO bus

Tags: linux, initialization, ethernet

I have a design based on i.MX6ULL processor where I need two Ethernet interfaces. The processor has two Ethernet controllers, FEC2 and FEC1. Each FEC has a PHY (LAN8720A) connected to it using RMII: FEC1 - PHY with address 0; FEC2 - PHY with address 1. The device is running Linux. It starts with running u-boot, which is stripped down to bare minimum (essentially it initializes RAM, NAND, and then starts Linux).

The problem which I'm facing is how to configure Linux so that it would be able to use both interfaces directly after power-on.

When the board gets powered, Linux first initializes FEC2, then probes the MDIO bus, then initializes FEC1. The result is that during probing one of the PHYs is getting no clock (from still inactive FEC1). Then Linux finds only the PHY connected to FEC2, and only this interface works correctly.

If now the board is rebooted (by command reboot or reset button, not by power-cycling), during start of Linux both FECs are already alive (they have been enabled during the previous start of the system), so both PHYs are found during probing the MDIO bus, and both interfaces are available for use.

Thus, my question is, if perhaps there is an elegant solution to this - how to get both FECs produce the clocks for their PHYs before Linux would probe the MDIO bus? I guess I could rely on u-boot with that. But, if anything else is possible, I would prefer to avoid having such unnecessary relation.

Best regards,
Adam